# Replace class manifest, js extension

Tags: class, replace

```
<div class="oldclass" style="" data-economy-item="A">
<div class="newclass" style="" data-economy-item="B">
```

Is there a way to replace the classes with extension?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question, if what you want to do is replace a class of your div you can use the following:

```
document.getElementByElement('div').removeClass('oldclass').addClass('newclass')
```

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

I would appreciate more information so we can help you.

Comment: Have a existing page (not mine). Ex: google.com. And here have any class, and i want to modify it to anyother class with chrome extension.